# Что такое Boilerplate code?

Tags: терминология

Читая разные статьи иногда сталкиваюсь с таким выражением :

> Boilerplate code

В моей команде внятно никто не смог объяснить это понятие. Что же это такое?

Comment: шаблон - заготовка

Comment: [Boilerplate code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

В Википедии же всё [написано](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code)

Понятие **boilerplate code** или **boilerplate** относится к секциям кода, которые должны быть написаны во многих местах с минимальными изменениями.
Часто используется по отношению к языкам, в которых программист должен написать много кода, чтобы выполнить минимальную задачу.

Многие современные IDE автоматически генерируют boilerplate код. Также существует такая вещь, как скаффолд (scaffold), который позволяет генерировать boilerplate (например, в Ruby on Rails можно генерировать базовые CRUD методы в контроллерах).

Примеры:

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Что такое Boilerplate code?</title>
```

Boilerplate code, который нам необходимо повторять в каждом шаблоне. ([Пруф](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea))

**JAVA**

```
public class Pet {
    private String name;
    private Person owner;

    public Pet(String name, Person owner) {
        this.name = name;
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Person getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(Person owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

P.S.: это главная причина, по которой я в своё время отказался от программирования на Java.

Comment: В вики на английском, а мне на русском хотелось. А в каком языке не нужно будет писать boilerplate код для приведенного выше примера?

Comment: Для html5 эта шкурка необязательна.

Comment: @koks_rs боюсь, что во всех. Но как сказано выше, многие IDE помогают писать его за вас, а многие фреймворки поддерживают скаффолдинг. Также в некоторых языках (Ruby, например), синтаксис упрощён настолько, что boilerplate становится минимальным. Например, базовый setter / getter там можно написать в одну строку.

Comment: @Qwertiy технически да, но без неё вы валидацию кода вряд-ли где пройдёте.

Comment: @Виктор, при корректном валидаторе - вполне себе проходится

Comment: @Виктор, валидацию пройду. Стандарт явно гноворит, какие теги необязательно писать и они будут дополнены автоматически. Минимальный валидный html-документ выглядит так: `<!doctype html><title>0</title>` - title пустым быть не должен. https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea

Comment: @Qwertiy спасибо, не знал такого

Comment: Boilerplate успешно преодолеватеся такими библиотеками, как, например, Lombok в Java.

Comment: Если говорить о языке который позволяет избежать boilerplate кода из примера на джаве, то это Kotlin.

Answer (score 13):

Шаблонный код, который должен быть написан во многих местах практически без изменений. Программисту приходится писать этот код каждый раз, как правило, занимая ненужное место, загромождая программу и отвлекая внимание от бизнес-логики. Это делает программу более сложной, без какой-либо пользы.

Comment: То есть, это негативные понятие, которого нужно избегать в коде?

Comment: @koks_rs, это понятие употребляют с негативной окраской, безусловно, чем менее многословен язык, тем лучше, но зачастую api библиотек или фреймворков написаны так, что избежать boilerplate code не получится.

Comment: Не сказал бы, что всегда с негативной.

Answer (score 5):

Часто на хитхабе есть проекты в которых много чего сделано из того что часто встречается в среднестатистическом проекте, эти проекты сделали чтобы их копировли и на их основе делали свои проекты, не заморачивались с одними и теми же вещами когда начинаешь делать проект. Такой проект еще называют starter.

Вот примеры: [html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate), [react-boilerplate](https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate), [electron-react-boilerplate](https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate), [laravel-5-boilerplate](https://github.com/rappasoft/laravel-5-boilerplate), [hackathon-starter](https://github.com/sahat/hackathon-starter).

Плюсы:

- Многие пакеты уже поставлены и настроены
- Написано много кода за Вас
- ̶ ̶Н̶е̶ ̶т̶а̶к̶ ̶м̶н̶о̶г̶о̶ ̶к̶о̶с̶т̶ы̶л̶е̶й̶ ̶в̶ ̶к̶о̶д̶е̶ ̶к̶а̶к̶ ̶е̶с̶л̶и̶ ̶б̶ы̶ ̶п̶и̶с̶а̶т̶ь̶ ̶с̶а̶м̶о̶м̶у̶

Минусы:

- Бывает в стартер входит инструменты которые не любишь или не хочешь использовать сейчас, приходиться выпиливать
- Порой не понятно благодаря какому коду что-то работает
- Бывает тяжело переделать код на свой лад
- Нет уверенности в коде потому как писал его не сам